# How to override libraries in Rails and django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

If the current third-party libraries do not meet your requirement, how to override it and do some customization?

In rails, libraries are from gems, only require them in configuration file, how to move source code of the library to app folder?

Comment: with all due respect, this was not a well-thought-out question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails: put your modified version to `./vendor`.  It's already in load order with higher priority than system-wide installed libraries

Django (and python in general): create some subdirectory for such libraries and add it to `PYTHONPATH` env variable, in front of other values.

Answer (score 1):

With Django, you can put a copy of the app into your project directory and modify it appropriately. I will assume that Rails can work similarly.